# Passing parameters from UITableViewCell to UITableView (Dynamic Content)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic-content

How might I pass my objects via parameters from my custom **UITableViewCell** class to my **UITableView**. Because I'm using **Dynamic Prototype Cells**, I can't assign my objects to the textviews within the cells. For this reason I need to pass my objects from class to class.

**MainTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


    if(!error)
    {
        for (NSDictionary * needs in jsonArray)
        {
            textNeedTitle.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needTitle"];
            textNeedPoster.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needPoster"];
            textNeedDescrip.text = [needs objectForKey: @"needDescrip"];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        textNeedTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error--%@",[error description]];
    }
    return cell;



    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

**TestTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textNeedTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textNeedPoster;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textNeedDescrip;
```

Each of the properties above are assigned via a Referencing Outlet to it's appropriate UITextView.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` you have `return cell;` I think you didn't paste your code correctly because that's a compile error.

Comment: @NealEhardt Missed that! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I noticed that in your UITableViewController you're getting a UITableViewCell instead of your custom class TestTableViewCell.
It should be like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Make sure that:
* In the storyboard, the reuse identifier of the cells is "Cell" (or a more appropriate name...)
* The class for the prototype cells is TestTableViewCell

Then you should be able to access the properties of the cell, like cell.textNeedTitle.text = @"Something"

Comment: Thank you for that heads up! I didn't realize I hadn't renamed that TableViewCell appropriately! To answer your question about what I'm trying to do: I am pulling sets of information that have been parsed from a JSON hierarchy of information from posts made by users. I currently have my php setup to send the 10 latest post to be parsed and populate the app's TestTableViewCell. Not sure if you could help me figure out how to make it stop posting only the last set of information in the list? Thanks again!